# what is the difference between compassion and sympathy?

Tags: word-meaning

I don't know how to distinguish the difference between compassion and sympathy. can you tell me how to tell with some examples?

Comment: If you google "difference between compassion sympathy empathy" you'll find hundreds of people asking and answering this question. You yourself could at least tell us what you found in dictionaries before asking here, but the bottom line is if so many people (many of them native Anglophones) need to ask, you can pretty much assume that ***there isn't much difference*** (many people regularly use all three words, even though they couldn't identify a clear-cut difference between them). Words only mean what speakers intend them to mean, so if we don't *know* a difference, there *is* no difference.

Comment: thanks for commenting!  I understand what you mean but I just wondered because when I read the thesis, they distinguish them. anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Lots of people will draw the fine distinction between ***sympathy** = feeling **pity** for someone **else** who's in dire circumstances* (circumstances which you the sympathiser aren't actually experiencing yourself), whereas feeling ***empathy*** is about ***having the same feelings they do*** (so you really "know how it feels"). In which context, ***compassion*** is pretty much the same as ***sympathy***, but ***empathy*** is subtly different. If any of those words are being used in the context of a thesis though, I would expect the writer to define his terms, because they're not "fixed".